# select common result from two sql query

Tags: mysql

query 1:

```
Select route_stop.Route_ID from route_stop,stop where
  route_stop.Stop_ID=stop.Stop_ID AND stop.Stop_Name='Agargaon'
```

query 2:

```
Select route_stop.Route_ID from route_stop,stop where
  route_stop.Stop_ID=stop.Stop_ID AND stop.Stop_Name='Mirpur-12'
```

Comment: Use a Join or something like this:

select * from 
(Select route_stop.Route_ID  as id from route_stop,stop where route_stop.Stop_ID=stop.Stop_ID AND stop.Stop_Name='Agargaon') a
where a.id in (
Select route_stop.Route_ID from route_stop,stop where route_stop.Stop_ID=stop.Stop_ID AND stop.Stop_Name='Mirpur-12')

Comment: i am understanding that you want both query results by a single query if it is not then please eleborate...

Answer (score 2):

```
Select route_stop.Route_ID from route_stop,stop where route_stop.Stop_ID=stop.Stop_ID AND stop.Stop_Name='Agargaon'
Union
Select route_stop.Route_ID from route_stop,stop where route_stop.Stop_ID=stop.Stop_ID AND stop.Stop_Name='Mirpur-12'
```

To join the same same column use union

Answer (score 0):

use as per below-

```
SELECT route_stop.Route_ID 
FROM route_stop,STOP 
WHERE route_stop.Stop_ID=stop.Stop_ID AND stop.Stop_Name IN ('Agargaon','Mirpur-12')
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Route_ID FROM route_stop JOIN stop ON route_stop.Stop_ID = stop.Stop_ID WHERE stop.Stop_Name='Agargaon' OR stop.Stop_Name='Mirpur-12'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, mate:

```
SELECT
    rs.Route_ID
FROM
    route_stop rs
    INNER JOIN stop s ON s.Stop_ID = rs.Stop_ID
WHERE
    s.Stop_Name IN ('Agargaon', 'Mirpur-12')
GROUP BY
    rs.Route_ID;
```